# How to get weekly unit test coverage report in powerbi desktop from sonar cloud

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, sonarcloud

We published unit test coverage report in powerBI desktop for bitbucket repository using sonar cloud APIs.

But that coverage is always pulls latest data after refresh.
Is there any way where we can find weekly coverage report like how much coverage was last week vs this week in power BI.

[image: sample report]